# Windows 7 Command Line Prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line-interface, uac

From a regular windows 7 command line, how do I launch the admin command prompt?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Local:

```
runas /user:LOCALCOMP\Administrator cmd
```

With AD-credentials:

```
runas /user:MYDOMAIN\Administrator cmd
```